# Как установить размер шрифта элементов для ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Выставляю в свойствах ListView FontSize="24", но на отображение текста элементов это никак не влияет, они такие же мелкие. Как задать размер шрифта для Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для "настройки" свойств элементов используйте свойство `ItemContainerStyle`. Пример:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
             <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
        </Style>
     </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Самый простой способ это переопределить `ItemTemplate` у `ListView`. Первый элемент `TextBlock` привязываете на свойство, которое должно отображаться маленьким шрифтом, второй элемент на свойство, которой должно отображаться большим.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Property1}" />
                  <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="{Binding Property2}" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Еще вопрос по этой же теме: у меня в каждом Item отображаются 2 строки (на самом деле одна с переносом). Можно ли сделать так, чтобы верхняя часть строки была меньшим шрифтом, а нижняя большим?

Comment: А как у вас сейчас отображение данных в `ListView` сделано? Покажите `XAML`  код.

Comment: У меня это делается динамически: идет обращение к БД, получаю коллекцию объектов, задаю ее в качестве ItemSource. У объекта переопределен метод ToString() в котором данные из двух полей объединяются в одну строку с \n между ними. И таким образом эти объекты выводятся в ListView.

Comment: Обновил ответ..